# Prove $(p\implies q)\implies(\neg q\implies\neg p)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given:

$L_1 :(\neg A\implies\neg B)\implies(A\implies B)$

$L_2 : \neg\neg A=A$

$L_3$ : Deduction theorem

$L_4$ : M.Ponens

$L_5$ : $A\implies(B\implies A)$

$L_6$ : $A\implies (B\implies C)\implies(A\implies B)\implies(A\implies C)$

Then prove : $(p\implies q)\implies(\neg q\implies\neg p)$

Proof:

1. assume $p\implies q$
2. assume $\neg\neg p$
3. by $L_2$, $\neg\neg p\implies p$
4. by 2, 3 and modus ponens, $p$

5)by 1, 2, and modus ponens $q$

Here I do not know how to get further.
Note i assumed $\neg\neg p$ in order to get $\neg\neg q$

Comment: this is really hard to read, could you reformat? Then people will be able to read your post and help

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq I suggested some edits which I think make the question clear. This does look like a good question, with actual effort, just really bad type setting. I don't think it should be down voted to smithereens

Comment: @user149368 it looks like you go wrong around step 2. Why do assume $\neg \neg p$ in order to get $\neg\neg q$. Mostly, why are you trying to get $\neg\neg q$?

Comment: THANK you indeed  for correcting my typing

Comment: Now if i can get $$\neg\neg q$$ ,from assuming $$\neg\neg p$$,then by using the deduction theorem i wiil get $$\neg\neg p\implies \neg\neg q$$.then by using  l_1 and deduction theorem can get the desired result

Answer (score 3):

So here is my best attempt at an answer. I will first give a standard deduction that $(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow(\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p)$. Then I will say a little bit about your set up.

To prove that $(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow(\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p)$, by the deduction theorem it suffices to assume $(p\Rightarrow q)$ and deduce $(\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p)$. So,

(1) assume $(p\Rightarrow q)$

Now, the goal is to prove $(\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p)$. By the deduction theorem, it suffices to assume $\neg q$ and deduce $\neg p$. So,

(2) assume $\neg q$.

Now we are looking to deduce $\neg p$. How does one prove negation? Well, we assume $p$ and show that this entails an abusrdity, i.e., a contradiction. This should have some intuitive appeal. So,

(3) assume $p$

Now we are looking to derive a contradiction. What contradiction can we find? Well,

(4) By (1), (3) and modus ponens, we derive $q$

(5) By (2) and (4), we derive $\neg q \land q$, a contradiction.

(6) By negation introduction, we discharge assumption (3) and derive $\neg p$.

(7) From the deduction theorem, we discharge assumption (2) and derive $\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$.

(8) Again, be the deduction theorem, we discharge assumption (1) and derive $(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow(\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p)$, as desired. QED.

This is a pretty standard derivation of the desired claim. However, it does not make use of the law of double negation (your premise $L_2$). I would say this is a virtue, since this tells us the desired claim holds even when double negation does not.

Also, this proof does not make use of $L_1$. Indeed, $L_1$ is unnecessary. The desired claim is actually a tautology: we can prove it from no assumptions. What is cool is it is a tautology in intuitionistic logic, so we don't even need double negation. So you have a pretty weird set up. Why are you asked to prove this claim under these particular assumptions?

Comment: Thanks, @ryang !

Comment: this a rather natural deduction ,which i am aware off and very aesy to prove. For example to prove $$a\implies a$$ USING the deduction theorem is one line proof.But using the 3 well known axioms of mathematical logic is very very difficult indeed. I was asked to prove the above using the axioms mentioned because the degree of the difficultyAnother proof by contradiction would be to accept $$p\implies q$$ and also the negation of $$\neg q\implies\neg p$$ and come into a contradiction

Comment: @user149368 is there a particular step in the above deduction which you are not allowed to use?

Comment: Your proof is not in the L language where the only logical symbols are -> and  negation while in your proof you use other logical symbols plus contradiction

Comment: @user149368 you did not mention such a restriction in your original post. If I find the time, I'll make an update. If you want someone to give you such an answer, you should edit your post to include all the requirements

Comment: please read my post again and tell me what should i add  more